# AWS CodePipeline is failing with InternalFailure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have migrated existing AWS Resources from one Cloudformation (CFT) stack to another CFT stack using below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html

After migration, my new CFT stack's status was "IMPORT_COMPLETE". Then I have created an AWS CodePipeline wherein my source is AWS CodeCommit and I am trying to deploy it in Cloudformation stack using CodePipeline.

In my CodePipeline I am using my new CFT stack where I have migrated my existing AWS resources and in the same template I have updated my code by added SQS queue policy and uploaded the code in CodeCommit.

So, when my AWS CodePipeline is getting triggered it is getting failed with "InternalFailure" error and it is not giving any specific error about why it is getting failed.

Also, I have checked into CloudTrail logs and there I can see my pipeline is getting failed after "UploadArchive" event which belongs to CodeCommit and it is nor moving further. Also, I tried to give administrator permission to my pipeline service role as well as cloudformation role but still the error is same.

Later, one thing I observed and that is when I update my new Cloudformation stack using AWS Cloudformation console then my stack's status is changing to "Update_Complete" status. Then after that if I try to update the code into CodeCommit then my pipeline is getting completed successfully.

So, not sure why my Pipeline is getting failed with "**InternalFailure**" when my stacks status is "IMPORT_COMPLETE". Could you please help me to understand if I am missing any specific step die to which my pipeline is getting failed with this error when my CFT stacks status is "IMPORT_COMPLETE" status

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in codepipeline. I'd recommend submitting at ticket to them in hopes they make a fix. I only found this out via support myself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened because I was using the GitHub version 1 action and I neglected to create the secret that contains the access token.